# Array of months with ranges

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, if-statement

I am currently trying to create an array that includes every month shortened down to 3 letters, etc. "JAN". I'd however like to assign every month with a specific range that can be used to etc. paste values.

I have tried the following to no avail: (Error: Subscript out of range)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = Worksheets("FH EXPORT").range("A2").Text
Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
Set genRng = ws.range("B2:B10")
Dim MonthName As Variant
MonthName = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

months(1) = ws.range("E2:E10")
months(2) = ws.range("F2:F10")
months(3) = ws.range("G2:E10")
months(4) = ws.range("H2:H10")
months(5) = ws.range("I2:I10")
months(6) = ws.range("J2:J10")
months(7) = ws.range("K2:K10")
months(8) = ws.range("L2:L10")
months(9) = ws.range("M2:M10")
months(10) = ws.range("N2:N10")
months(11) = ws.range("O2:N10")
months(12) = ws.range("P2:P10")
If InStr(1, celltxt, "JAN") Then
months(1).Value = genRng.Value
ElseIf InStr(1, celltxt, "FEB") Then
months(2).Value = genRng.Value
Else
    MsgBox ("not found")
End If
End Sub
```

The whole reason for me attempting this is actually to avoid creating an if statement for every single month, also as shown in the code.

Comment: Could you show some data and expected output? Are you trying to lookup a month and if present change the month in some other cells?

Comment: Excel range is a two dimensional array always.

Comment: As shown here:
    celltxt = Worksheets("FH EXPORT").range("A2").Text what I do is test a cell in another sheet if it contains the word "JAN", "FEB" etc. and then act on that, in this case acting would be to copy some data from the genRng to the specified months range

Comment: Your months array also starts at 1 not 0 but has only 11 values stated and as @cyboashu states, when you read in from sheet you create a 2d array which will start at 1 but presumably you want to end at 12?

Comment: Well yes, I would need it to start at 1 and end at 12 to make sense further down to clarify the individual months. I added the last month, that was a whoopsie :P

Comment: What happens if cell A2 contains the substring but not as part of a month name e.g. Juniper? I don't know what is in that field but can you always be sure this is ok? i.e. is it usually the full month name in this field or the short name with year etc? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: The cell A2 will always contain either "JAN" or another shortened down version of the month, since it's an export of some software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

**Version 1: Simpler**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim celltxt As String, ws As Worksheet, genRng As Range, MonthNames,  i As Long
    celltxt = Worksheets("FH EXPORT").Range("A2").Text
    Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
    Set genRng = ws.Range("B2:B10")
    MonthNames = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

    For i = LBound(MonthNames) To UBound(MonthNames)
      'split celltxt on the search string MonthNames(i) e.g. Jan and test to see if resultant array has more than 1 item (ubound indicates number) i.e. was able to split because was present
       ' add an Or in case celltxt is only 3 characters long and is a match e.g. celltxt is Jan only.
         If UBound(Split(LCase$(celltxt), LCase$(MonthNames(i)))) > 0 Or LCase$(celltxt) = LCase$(MonthNames(i)) Then
            ws.Range("E2:E10").Offset(, i) = genRng.Value
            End
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("not found")
End Sub
```

**Version 2:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim celltxt As String, ws As Worksheet, genRng As Range, MonthNames, i As Long, found As Boolean
    celltxt = Worksheets("FH EXPORT").Range("A2").Text
    Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
    Set genRng = ws.Range("B2:B10")
    MonthNames = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec") '<==array holding the month abbreviations

    For i = LBound(MonthNames) To UBound(MonthNames) 'loop the entire array e.g. Jan, Feb
        On Error Resume Next 'prepare for if not found error being thrown
        If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(LCase$(MonthNames(i)), LCase$(celltxt))) Then 'test if error returned i.e. value not found
            GoTo NextLine 'if error found then current array item e.g. Jan was not found so go to the line that says NextLine
        Else
            ws.Range("E2:E10").Offset(, i) = genRng.Value 'no error so we know found and can set
            End 'exit progam as found
        End If
ResumeLine:
    Next i
    If Not found Then MsgBox ("not found")
    Exit Sub
NextLine:   'this handles the error by clearing it and then sending the program back to loop to try again with next array item e.g. Feb
    Err.Clear 'clear error
    GoTo ResumeLine 'go back to next i
End Sub
```

Version 3 using LCase$ for comparison

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim celltxt As String, ws As Worksheet, genRng As Range, MonthNames, i As Long
    celltxt = LCase$(Worksheets("FH EXPORT").Range("A2").Text)
    Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
    Set genRng = ws.Range("B2:B10")
    MonthNames = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

    For i = LBound(MonthNames) To UBound(MonthNames)

        If InStr(1, celltxt, LCase$(MonthNames(i))) > 0 Then
            ws.Range("E2:E10").Offset(, i) = genRng.Value
            End
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("not found")
End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies Samuel, I was unable to create a chat so couldn't move the discussion due to low reputation, still new on this site :)

Comment: btw `MonthName` is VBA function, and `MonthName(12, 1)` = "Dec"

Comment: @Slai. Thank you. Very true. How did I miss that! Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need an array? you could just generate month names on the fly:

```
Dim celltxt As String
Dim genRng  As Range
Set genRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
celltxt = Worksheets("FH EXPORT").range("A2").Text
For m_ = 1 To 12
    If (InStr(1, UCase(celltxt), UCase(Format(DateSerial(1, m_, 1), "mmm")))) > 0 Then
        ws.Range("D2:D10").Offset(0, m_).Value = genRng.Value
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next m_
```

Explanation:

example for `m_ = 1`

> DateSerial(1, m_, 1)

Line above generates a date object with value "1/1/2001"

> Format(DateSerial(1, m_, 1), "mmm")

Line above generates "Jan"

> UCase(Format(DateSerial(1, m_, 1), "mmm")

Line above generates "JAN"

And then you compare your A2 cell's uppercase value `UCase(celltxt)` against this "JAN" and copy your range accordingly to your destination, starting from your E column, ofsetted by the month number `m_` from the loop.

**UPDATE:**

hehe if cell A2 always has 3 letters short month, then here is a one liner:

```
Worksheets("Report").Range("D2:D10").Offset(0, Month(DateValue(Right(Left(Split(Worksheets("FH EXPORT").Range("A2").Text, " ")(1), 5), 3) & " 1"))).Value = Worksheets("Report").Range("B2:B10").Value
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time and assisting me! I however do get a few issues with yours and it seems to be pasting a bit wrong, appreciate you taking the time though to assist. This can definitely also be regarded as a partial-solution

Comment: @Boringuity you're welcome. i've updated the answer with a 1 line solution if you want. in case something doesnt work properly, let me know and i will fix it.

Comment: I attempted your one-liner however it's just erroring out when I attempt running it sadly.
No need to spend more time on it though for my sake, thanks for the assistance anyway

Comment: @Boringuity don't worry i simply enjoy this :D (i fixed the 1 liner)

Comment: @Boringuity that would happen when vba is unable to find a date value in the `datevalue` function. is there other data in cell A2 except the 2 letters month name?

Comment: Yes! As I covered in the comments above there actually is, which is also why I used the Str() before, here is an example of how it could look.
Period 01FEB18 0001 to 31FEB18 2259

Comment: @Boringuity how about now :)

Comment: I tested it now, it works perfectly. However it's a bit difficult to actually customize the code when it's just one line haha